# Minting an ERC20 from another non-ERC20 contract

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, mint

I am trying to build a contract that mints different LP tokens to represent positions in liquidity pools.

My main contract creates instances of my lpToken contract (an ERC20) and stores them in a list of Pool data structures.

For some reason, I can't find a way to mint new lpTokens from my main contract, I get the error:

> TypeError: *Member "mint" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract ERC20.*

Here's a stripped-down version of my code:

```
struct Pool {
    IERC20 tokenA;
    IERC20 tokenB;

    uint256 tokenALocked;
    uint256 tokenBLocked;

    ERC20 lpToken;
}
```

```
contract lpToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor(string memory name, string memory ticker) ERC20(name, ticker) {}

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }
    
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return balanceOf(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

```
contract ShittySwap {
    Pool[] public pools;

    function addPool(address tokenA, address tokenB) public {
        lpToken newLp = new lpToken("ShittyLP", "SLP");
        pools.push(Pool(IERC20(tokenA), IERC20(tokenB), 0, 0, newLp));
    }

    function addLiquidity(
            uint pool,
            IERC20 tokenA,
            IERC20 tokenB,
            uint qtyA,
            uint qtyB
        ) public {
        Pool memory swapPool = pools[pool];

        { ... doing stuff here ... }

        uint lpTokensToMint = {...someNumber...};

        swapPool.lpToken.mint(msg.sender, lpTokensToMint); // The error comes from this line
    }

    { ... }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the IERC20/ERC20 interface there is no mint function. You should change Pool’s lptoken to:

```
struct Pool {
    IERC20 tokenA;
    IERC20 tokenB;

    uint256 tokenALocked;
    uint256 tokenBLocked;

    lptoken lpToken;
 }
```

Comment: I knew my problem was simpler than what I thought...
That works perfectly (and makes sense to me), thank you very much for your time!